# Getting a PERMISSION_DENIED response from all my browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

Our website `http://www.monfatec.com` is using the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function to get the long and lat of the client.

But it always responds with a `PERMISSION_DENIED` status, this, whatever the browser and client, from both `Firefox 58.0.1` and `Chromium 64.0.32` on my Linux pc, as well as from `Chrome 64.0.32` on my smartphone, and it is consistent and occurs on every request.

The website uses `http` and not `https` and that might be an explanation for the issue, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS.

This will also be the case in update versions of most other browsers.